# What's the purpose of declaring restriction tag without any facet?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I came across a situation where I found an element defined via a `simpleType`, and this `simpleType` has a restriction without any facet declared inside it.

```
<xs:element name="elementWithRestrictionTag">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:normalizedString" />
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

What's the use of declaring an element just to decide its type by having a restriction if I can do it simply like:

```
<xs:element name="elementWithoutRestrictionTag" type="xs:normalizedString"/>
```

I already made some search over the internet but none of results explained this. Why in the W3C recommendation would this not be shown as **not-recommended** in the first place?

Comment: In the first case you could add more restrictions like `xs:minLength`, `xs:maxLength` etc. Obviously if you use it only to decide its type it makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that both forms are equivalent; they will allow and reject the same set of XML documents.

Possible reasons for an empty `xs:restriction`:

1. Signal intent to add restrictions later.
2. Achieve implementation-specific effect in downstream tool chain
   links.
3. Upstream tool chain link didn't simplify empty restriction to
   unrestricted base type.